# How do I add an external power socket to a lighting circuit?

Tags: electrical, lighting, uk, socket

I'm installing some ELV garden lights and would be grateful for some advice on connecting up.
I'd like to control them from a spare light switch (the 2nd switch controls the exterior wall lights) just inside the back door as I have a cable already in place from an extension previously. The switch is currently wired brown (live) in/out of switch 1, the neutral is isolated in a block and the earth is connected to the backbox terminal. Considering I am trying to run low voltage lighting (6 x 3v) how should I wire switch 2, should I connect live/neutral and earth and similar to the outside socket? For info there[image] is a plugged adaptor with the garden lights and outdoor socket will be IP66 rated.

Thanks in advance for your advice.
Bren

Comment: The outside socket had a earth from the metal box to the metal strap on the box. You should continue the earth wire to the new box. But I work on the other side of the pond. If the new box is not conductive and the low voltage power supply is 2 wire connected it may not mater but I do not know your codes.

Comment: I don't know UK codes either, but the bit of exposed copper on the hot, brown wire going into the switch doesn't look right. Also, big wads of electrical tape always make me wary. It may be perfectly legal and quite safe, but my inclination would be to double check what's hiding under there to ensure it was done properly, especially since some of the tape is torn.

Comment: Thanks guys, for info the switch socket shown is internal and I've corrected the shortcomings in wiring and isolating (you never know until you open it up). The proposed external socket will be IP66 rated so all good there. Q is do I connect all the neutrals to give continuity to the external socket?

Comment: Also note that only special colored tape is rated as an insulator.  Much of it is rated only as marking tape, so that tape should probably be replaced to be on the safe side.